# Password issue in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

In CakePHP, is it possible to use username and password of one project(e.g: project-1) to another project (e.g.project-2) directly coping from database of Project-1?

Here I'll not give username and password manually,but making copy from database fields of project-1 and paste into the username and password field of project-2 login page.

Does it create any problem for password hashing of cake? if there is any problem, what are the possible solutions?Please help me with solutions.

thanks in advance for solution and sorry in advance for any mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I can't see why you would have any issues at all if you are just copying data across. You might want to ensure that your `security.salt` is the same in both projects to ensure that the encoding matches the passwords correctly.

Also you users will need to use the same login details.

There is always the possibility of using an OpenID, or building an API layer in project1, which will authenticate people in project2.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that you should take note of is to ensure that the value for `security.salt` listed in *your-app-folder*/config/core.php is the same in both projects.